# Unable to run protractor config within gulp getting ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, gulp, protractor, gulp-protractor

Below is a screenshot of my code, when I run selenium by itself, the scripts run fine. But when I try to start webdriver within gulp (what my goal is)  I am getting:

```
 Error code: 135
[12:48:27] E/launcher - Error message: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0
.1:4444
[12:48:27] E/launcher - Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Any advice is appreciated.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeGM2.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask questions.

Comment: This usually happens when the selenium server isn't running. Are you sure the server has started before you start the tests? Try running `webdriver-manager start` after your update. This will run in the foreground though so you will likely not want it to be part of your gulp task since it won't exit. I typically use `directConnect: true` when I'm running locally. That way I don't have to worry about starting the server.

Comment: Yea, when I run start by itself it works fine, but I’m trying to start webdriver within the gulp task

Answer (score 0):

I feel this is on the network side issue - 127.0.0.1 this IP and 4444 port number might be not able to connect to the server, i faced the same type of error and when looked it was the host being stopped to connect to the server - might be some firewalls - that was in my case which looks similar to me.